# JTree : Why does my directory don't appear like a directory?

Tags: java, nodes, jtree, expand

Exploring the JTree component, I wrote a small class that will list the directories and files of my hard disk. To avoid a "full scan" which would takes longs minutes and would be a waste of time and ressources, I decided that I'll explore only 1 sub level of the "active node". By "active node", I mean the directory clicked OR the node expanded.

For the directory clicked, it works perfectly : I can explore my directories and subdirectories, the code works "sub level by sub level" and the directories clicked appears like directories.

But if I expand a node, it fail ! The method to explore the children of this nodes runs ; it find all the children and can list them via a "System.out.println(...)", but my directories still appears like files even if they have children. To have the directory appears like a directory, I have to click on it (=using the "first method").

Here is my code. Does someone could explain me what is failing ?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.event.TreeExpansionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeExpansionListener;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class Explorer2 extends JPanel {
private JTree tree;
private DefaultMutableTreeNode root= new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
int countSubLevel=0;
int limit=1;

Explorer2() {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode driveNode=null;
    for (File file:File.listRoots()) {
        driveNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file.getAbsolutePath());
        //testLeaf(driveNode);          
        exploreDirectory(file, driveNode);
        root.add(driveNode);
    }

    displayTree();
}

Explorer2(String rootDirectory) {
    File file = new File(rootDirectory);
    DefaultMutableTreeNode directoryNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file.getAbsolutePath());
    exploreDirectory(file, directoryNode);
    root.add(directoryNode);
    displayTree();
}

public void exploreDirectory (File dir, DefaultMutableTreeNode dirNode) {
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        //System.out.println(dir+" (parent) is a directory. Its level is : "+dirNode.getLevel());
        try {
            for (File file:dir.listFiles()) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode fileNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file.getAbsolutePath()); 

                dirNode.add(fileNode);
                //System.out.println(dirNode+" - "+file+" - Level = "+fileNode.getLevel());
                /*
                if (fileNode.getLevel()<limit) {
                    System.out.println(file+" (child) have a level : "+fileNode.getLevel());
                    exploreDirectory(file, fileNode);
                } else {
                    //System.out.println("Not in the loop : "+fileNode.getLevel());
                }
                */

            }

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.err.println(dir+" generates a NullPointerException");
        }           

    } else {
        System.out.println(dir+" is a file. Its level is : "+dirNode.getLevel());
    }
    countSubLevel+=1;
}

public void displayTree () {
    DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
    tree = new JTree(treeModel);
    //tree = new JTree(root);
    tree.setRootVisible(true);
    tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new MyTreeSelectionListener());
    tree.addTreeExpansionListener(new MyTreeExpansionListener());


    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(new JScrollPane(tree), BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void testLeaf(DefaultMutableTreeNode dir) {
    if (dir.isLeaf()) {
        System.out.println("Rien en dessous de "+dir);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Creuse !");
    }
}

class MyTreeSelectionListener implements TreeSelectionListener {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent arg0) {
        if (tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent() != null) {
            File dir = new File(tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent().toString());
            DefaultMutableTreeNode dirNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) arg0.getPath().getLastPathComponent();
            DefaultMutableTreeNode fileNode=null;
            //System.out.println(dirNode.getChildCount());
            if (dirNode.getChildCount()==0) {
                System.out.println("The directory is : "+dir+" - Node : "+dirNode);
                exploreDirectory(dir, dirNode);
            }
        }

    }

}

class MyTreeExpansionListener implements TreeExpansionListener {

    @Override
    public void treeCollapsed(TreeExpansionEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Collapsed : "+arg0.getPath().getLastPathComponent());
    }

    @Override
    public void treeExpanded(TreeExpansionEvent arg0) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode dir = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) arg0.getPath().getLastPathComponent();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode fileNode=null;
        System.out.println("Expanded directory is : "+dir+" - Number of child : "+dir.getChildCount());         
        for (int i=0 ; i<dir.getChildCount() ; i++) {

            File file = new File(dir.getChildAt(i).toString());
            fileNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file.getAbsolutePath());
            exploreDirectory(file, fileNode);
            System.out.println("*"+i+" - directory is : "+dir+" - Files are : "+file+" - Number of children : "+fileNode.getChildCount());
        }           
    }       
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame ();
    window.setSize(500, 600);
    window.setTitle("Explorateur");
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    String str = System.getProperty("user.home");
    //Explorer2 explorer = new Explorer2(str);
    Explorer2 explorer = new Explorer2();

    window.getContentPane().add(explorer);
    window.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Thanks to all the answers. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `TreeModel` class, such as `DefaultTreeModel`, to serve as the model for the nodes in the tree. It has methods for the system to determine if a given node is a leaf or not, and whether to allow any node to contain children or whether (as in your case) only certain nodes can contain children.

Your program doesn't use a model of its own, so the `JTree` just creates its own; since there's no way for the model it creates to tell whether a node is a leaf or not unless it's expanded, then it doesn't know it's a parent node with children until it's expanded and the listener adds nodes to it.

Comment: You are using DefaultTreeModel with DefaultMutableTreeNodes, they can't know whether a given node is a subtree or a leaf. Either extend DefaultMutableTreeNode and put a reference to the File object in eadh node, or put the File object in the setUserObject in each DefaultMutableTreeNode instance. Then override isLeaf in an extension of DefaultTreeModel, and examine your file object in the given node to determine whether it has children. Swing will call this to determine how to display the node.